# How to find the average in javascript?

Tags: javascript

So I'm fairly new to JavaScript but I cannot seem to find the average in my code. I want to understand why my average is not working. Any help you guys?

```js
function getEvenOdd() {
  var oddSum = 0;
  var evenSum = 0;
  var num = 0;
  var evenAvg = 0;
  var oddAvg = 0;

  while (true) {
    num = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number(-1 to exit)"));
    if (num == -1) {
      break;
    }
    if (num % 2 == 0) {
      evenSum += num;
    } else {
      oddSum += num;
    }
    evenAvg = evenSum / num;
    oddAvg = oddSum / num;
  }
  alert("Sum of all even numbers is: " + evenSum);
  alert("Sum of all odd numbers is: " + oddSum);
  alert("Average of all even numbers is : " + evenAvg);
  alert("Average of all odd numbers is: " + oddAvg);
}
```

Comment: your issue isn't how to use javascript, it's what average is - average is the total of values divided by number of values - your code does total of values divided by the last number entered ... so the average of 8,4,2, 10 is  (8+4+2+10)/4 ... not (8+4+2+10)/10

Answer (score 1):

On your code, to calculate the `oddAvg` and `evenAvg`, you have divided `evenSum` and `oddSum` by `num` variable (which is input from `prompt`).

And as you know, `average` = `total sum` / `total count`, so it's not right to divide the sum by the input `number` variable.

Instead of that, you need to calculate the count of `odd` and `even` numbers and divide the `even` and `odd` sum by the `even` and `odd` number counts as follows.

```js
function getEvenOdd() {
  var oddSum = 0;
  var evenSum = 0;
  var num = 0;
  var evenAvg = 0;
  var oddAvg = 0;
  var evenCount = 0;
  var oddCount = 0;

  while (true) {
    num = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number(-1 to exit)"));
    if (num == -1) {
      break;
    }
    if (num % 2 == 0) {
      evenSum += num;
      evenCount ++;
    } else {
      oddSum += num;
      oddCount ++;
    }
  }
  
  evenAvg = evenSum / evenCount;
  oddAvg = oddSum / oddCount;
  alert("Sum of all even numbers is: " + evenSum);
  alert("Sum of all odd numbers is: " + oddSum);
  alert("Average of all even numbers is : " + evenAvg);
  alert("Average of all odd numbers is: " + oddAvg);
}

getEvenOdd();
```

Answer (score 0):

These operations are dividing the `evenSum` or `oddSum` by the last input `num`.

```
evenAvg = evenSum / num; 
oddAvg = oddSum / num;
```

You should divide the sum by the number of even or odd inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of evenSum / num use evenSum/Count of Numbers entered.

Answer (score 0):

How about this solution? It is aiming to store odd and even numbers into oddList and evenList.

```js
function getEvenOdd() {
var evenAvg = 0;
var oddAvg = 0;

var oddList = [];
var evenList = [];
var num = 0;

while (true) {
    num = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number(-1 to exit)"));
    if (num == -1) {
      break;
    }
    if (num % 2 == 0) {
      evenList.push(parseInt(num));
    } else {
      oddList.push(parseInt(num));
    }

    evenAvg = evenList.reduce((p, c) => p + c, 0) / evenList.length;
    oddAvg = oddList.reduce((p, c) => p + c, 0) / oddList.length;
}
alert("Sum of all even numbers is: " + evenList.length);
alert("Sum of all odd numbers is: " + oddList.length);
alert("Average of all even numbers is : " + evenAvg);
alert("Average of all odd numbers is: " + oddAvg);
}

getEvenOdd();
```